# Adding a Jira Issue/Filter Macro with variables in Confluence template

Tags: variables, macros, jira, confluence

I am creating a template in Confluence with a variable called $epic. I want to have a several Jira Issue/Filter macros. I want all these Macros to filter issues using the $epic variable.

The Template's code looks like this

```
<h1>Roadmap</h1>
<h2>Project 1</h2>
<p>
  <ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="columns">key,summary,type,created,updated,due,assignee,reporter,priority,status,resolution</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="server">jira.company.com JIRA</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="serverId"><serv-Id-num></ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="jqlQuery">project = "PROJ1" AND Epic = $epic  </ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="maximumIssues">20</ac:parameter>
  </ac:structured-macro>
</p>
<p> </p>
```

I would have several of these for different projects. This doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to include your code in a confluence user macro so you can pass the epic parameter.